# Apply chart range filter in Google Table

Tags: google-visualization

I need to apply chart range filter based on date on hidden column in google table. For this i created Google table instance like this

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
```

i added the column in this table then i created google dataview object like this

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
        view.hideColumns([0]);
```

where `data` is datatable instance from here i hiding the first column but instead of hiding it's getting deleted. How t ojust hide this column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `view.columns` parameter of the Table's ChartWrapper object.  This creates a private DataView for the Table to use, showing only the columns you specify in the columns parameter, eg:

```
view: {
    // show only columns 1-4 in the Table
    columns: [1, 2, 3, 4]
}
```